# How to send SMS-COMMAND?

Tags: sms, gsm, pdu

The GSM 03.40 specifies a message of type `SMS-COMMAND` which lets the sender perform operations at the SMSC (e.g. inquiry, delete, etc.) on a previously sent message using its associated `TP-MR` value.

I have a GSM 2G modem (SIMCom SIM808) that I use for test purposes. It is configured for SMS in PDU mode.

I can successfully send `SMS-SUBMIT` messages and process `SMS-DELIVERY`, `SMS-SUBMIT-REPORT` and `SMS-STATUS-REPORT` messages \o/

Now, I would like to play with the `SMS-COMMAND` messages. However, when sending such PDUs, the modem answers with `+CMS ERROR: 304` which means "Invalid PDU mode".

My guess is that the SMSC somehow filters out these messages and tells the modem "invalid mode".. But that's just a guess and I hope it is wrong!

Here is my test scenario:

## 1 - Send a `SMS-SUBMIT` message

I send a `SMS-SUBMIT` message with the `TP-SRR` and `TP-MR` fields set to the proper value. As the destination device is off-line so the message is expected to be kept pending at SMSC.

### PDU dump

```
PDU: 0031990B913316325476F80000050141

{
    .sca_format.raw = 0x00,
    .sca = "",
    .sca_len = 0,
    .type.raw = 0x31,
    .submit.mr = 0x99,
    .submit.da_format.raw = 0x91,
    .submit.da_len = 12,
    .submit.da = "+33612345678",
    .submit.pid = 0x00,
    .submit.dcs = 0x00,
    .submit.vp_mn = 30,
    .submit.vp_abs = "",
    .submit.vp_tz = 0,
    .submit.udl = 1,
    .submit.udhl = 0,
    .submit.udh = NULL,
    .submit.ud_len = 1,
    .submit.ud = "A",
}
```

### AT command

```
AT+CMGS=15\r
> 0031990B913316325476F80000050141\x1a
+CMGS: 153
OK
```

## 2 - Send a `SMS-COMMAND`

Then I send a `SMS-COMMAND` message which is set to inquiry the previously sent message.

Note that an `SMS-COMMAND` set for deleting the previously sent message answers the same.

### PDU dump

```
PDU: 00229A0000990B913316325476F800

{
    .sca_format.raw = 0x00,
    .sca = "",
    .sca_len = 0,
    .type.raw = 0x22,
    .command.mr = 0x9a,
    .command.pid = 0x00,
    .command.ct = 0x00,
    .command.mn = 0x99,
    .command.da_format.raw = 0x91,
    .command.da_len = 12,
    .command.da = "+33612345678",
    .command.cdl = 0,
    .command.cd_len = 0,
    .command.cd = "",
}
```

### AT command

```
AT+CMGS=14\r
> 00229A0000990B913316325476F800\x1a
+CMS ERROR: 304
```

## 3 - Bring destination mobile online

Finally I bring the destination device back online and it receives the pending `SMS-SUBMIT` message. A few seconds after, I receive a `SMS-STATUS-REPORT` which confirms the successful delivery.

## 4 - Questions

**Q1**: Is the `SMS-COMMAND` message malformed?

**Q2**: Is the `SMS-COMMAND` type even supported on the SMSC side?

**Q3**: Any clue to make this work?